# What is the value of $e^{i \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, complex-numbers, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

Context:
There is a **Unitary Matrix** given: $\bf{U}=e^{i\pi\frac{\bf{H}}{2}}$ where $\bf{H}$ is a **Hermitian matrix**. And
$\bf{H}=\sqrt{3}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\\0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&0\\\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}&0&-\frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$

The question is: What is the $\bf{U}$ matrix?

My knowledge says *all terms of* $\bf{H}$ *matrix have to be raised into exponentials and multiplied by* $i\frac{\pi}{2}$. I.e, $\bf{(2,2)}$ term of $\bf{U}$ matrix will be $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}}=i$.

So in that case what will be the $\bf{(1,1)}$ term?
I am at $e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}.$

Is it correct?

The given *answer* for $\bf{U}$ matrix is $\bf{U}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}&0&i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\\0&i&0\\i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}&0&-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\end{bmatrix}$.

So there are two questions:
$1.$ Am I doing it correctly in going from $\bf{H}$ to $\bf{U}$?
$2.$ If I am correctly doing it then is $e^{i \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$? How?

Comment: Have you consulted e.g. Wikipedia or any textbook on how exponentials of (hermitian) matrices are defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $e^{i \frac \pi 2 \frac 1 {\sqrt 3}} \ne \frac i {\sqrt 3}$ because the modulus of the left hand side is $1$ and the modulus of the right hand side is $\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}$. To calculate the Hermitian matrix you have to expand the exponential as a Taylor series :

$\mathbf {U} = \mathbf {I} + i \frac \pi 2 \mathbf {H} + \frac 1 {2!} \left(i \frac \pi 2 \mathbf {H} \right)^2 + \frac 1 {3!} \left(i \frac \pi 2 \mathbf {H} \right)^3 + \dots$

Noting that $\mathbf{H}^2 = \mathbf I$, this simplifies to

$\mathbf {U} = \mathbf {I} + i \frac \pi 2 \mathbf {H} - \frac 1 {2!} \left(\frac \pi 2 \right )^2 \mathbf I - \frac i {3!} \left(\frac \pi 2 \right)^3 \mathbf H + \dots = \mathbf I \cos \frac \pi 2 + i \mathbf H \sin \frac \pi 2 = i \mathbf H$